# when using a case statement to aggregate fields in redshift, is it more performant to replace binary fields with 1s and 0s?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For example, which of the following calculations should perform faster?

```
sum ( 
    case 
        when fieldA is not null
        then 1
        else 0
    end ) total
```

or

```
sum ( 
    case 
        when fieldA is not null
        then fieldB -- binary field, 1 or 0. 
    end ) total
```

For the sake of this example, assume that when fieldA is not null, fieldB will always equal 1. fieldB can also equal 1 if fieldA is null, which is why I use the case statement.

Comment: Referencing one column should be more efficient than referencing two.

Comment: SUM(binary), does that work?

Comment: @jarlh sum(binary) won't work because fieldB can equal 1 even if fieldA is null. In this example, I only want to count fieldB if fieldA is NOT null.

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is what i'm assuming as well, but i'm hoping for a more detailed answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two queries do not do the same thing, unless `fieldB` is uniformly `1` (or uniformly `1` when `fieldA` is not `NULL`).  In general, you should run the query that does what you really need.

Redshift is a columnar database.  That means that every column used in a query adds overhead to the execution.

Hence, it is better to avoid reading a column if you can.  Of course, if the column is referenced elsewhere in the query, then this does not apply.

In addition, `SUM()` operates on numbers.  I'm not sure if "binary" means that the value is a number.  If not, then it needs to be converted, which also adds overhead.